# How to get key and value from a string

Tags: java, regex

I have a question about how to write a regex expression to get the key and value pairs from below string?

```
{"ReturnCode":"0","ErrorMsg":"success","EncryToken":"@@xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"}
```

Could someone help me learn on what this can be done?

Thanks very much.

Comment: Use [JSON in Java](http://json.org/java/)

Comment: this is JSON response , right ??

Answer (score 3):

This one should suit your needs:

```
"([^"]+)"\s*:\s*"([^"]+)"
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

The key is in the first group, the value in the second one.

Visualization by [Debuggex](https://www.debuggex.com/r/k3udjBsbiuJw848_)

Comment: This may be right, but its a very very bad idea to parse, a what seems to be a proper JSON, as a String using regex.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Java JSON or the Google Gson to parse this JSON string ...
as illustrated here - http://answers.oreilly.com/topic/257-how-to-parse-json-in-java/